# Wi-Fi cannot be used, it says it is disabled by a hardware switch (I do not have a disable WiFi hardware switch on my laptop)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu onto my Lenovo Yoga 2 and I cannot turn on or use my WiFi  because it says that it is disabled by a hardware switch (I do not have a physial disable WiFi hardware switch on my laptop)

I have tried several drivers installed via USB to no avail. And I do not have an Ethernet port so installing a driver that way isn't an option.

So how can I enable my WiFi?

Comment: Try executing `rfkill unblock all` from a terminal.

Comment: Does your wireless come to life if you do: `sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop`? If so, I will propose a permanent solution.  Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: May be your laptop has a key combination (usually function key + F5 or F3) to turn on the WIFI. You can find some key combinations for different manufacturers [here](http://internethelp.centurylink.com/internethelp/wireless-how-to-turn-on-off-wireless-on-laptops.html)

Comment: Yes thank you so much!!! chili555

Answer (score 1):

If your wireless works after removing `ideapad-laptop`, let's blacklist it so it doesn't load in the future. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

This Yoga2 problem has been fixed in kernel 3.16.
If you installed Ubuntu 14.04, then run

sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic

Permanent blacklist of ideapad_laptop is not a good solution.
If you did it already, remove "blacklist ideapad-laptop" from
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf